# Check if there's a duplicate in an array using an hash-table

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, hash, time-complexity

> Goal: Check if there's a duplicate number in an array with the size of `n`.

Basically if we may use an hash-table (open-hash, with linked list), then we could iterate the array and insert the numbers to the table with some value (could be `1`, doesn't really matter).
While iterating, if the cell isn't empty then we have a duplicate number.

Since we know that the **expected** time for read/write is `O(1)` then the expected time for the algorithm is `O(n)`.

**Question #1:** Why is the worst-case equal `O(nlogn)`?
**Question #2:** Would you do it differently then the solution suggested?

Comment: #1 - The worst case is not O(n log n).    It is O(n) assuming your hash is O(1), which is a reasonable assumption.  #2 - it really is application dependent.  For example, if you expect the array to be huge, then this method won't work because your hash table would get big and take up a lot of memory.

Comment: @thang No, it is not O(n) worst case. However, the worst case of hash tables is really rare and is usually ignored (unless for time sensitive real time apps)

Comment: @amit, it depends on the implementation of the hash table.  Under the assumption that the hash table has O(1) worst case, then this is surely O(n).  For example, consider a hash function as the identity function.  That is sure to guarantee O(1).

Comment: @thang The assumption of O(1) worst case insertion to hash table is the problem. It is not, due to collisions of elements. It is however O(1) expected amortized time.

Comment: @amit, read the second part of my previous comment.

Comment: @thang Using the identity function requires unrealistic usage of space, it is the same as just using a bitset, which is unfeasible for these kind of problems. The whole point of hash table is the "universe" of elements (all possible elements) is significantly larger than the number of actual elements you need to store, and is unstoreable.

Comment: @amit, again, it depends on the application.  if your #s are guaranteed to be between 0 and 1000, for example, then it's not unrealistic.  also, the hash function can guarantee each bucket to have no more than k elements where k is constant.  there are also other ways of dealing with collision than using BST (e.g. re-hash, etc.).

Comment: Rehashing is basically using [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing), and is O(n) worst case search. No hash function can **guarantee** (again, worst case) at most `k` elements per bean for infinite size universe and unknown (or n>k to be precise) number of elements.

Comment: Why not instead use a `HashSet`? Saves you memory and runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here, I assume the author referred to a variant of hash table, where in each "bin" there is a BST (or some other deterministic DS), and thus in the worst case, all elements are inserted to the same bin repeatidly - and that requires `O(nlogn)` overall.

However, hash tables are seldom implemented this way, because this worst case is very unlikely, and a regular linked list is implemented in this implementation, for this case - the worst case will be `O(n^2)` for this solution.

The other alternative to approach this problem is sort, and iterate to find duplicates (easy in sorted arrays), this is `O(nlogn)` with significantly less memory usage.

This problem is known as the [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), and these two options (with some variants maybe) are the ways to solve it. 

It is known to be `Omega(nlogn)` without using extra memory and hashing.

Comment: Yeah, actually it was mentioned that every bean contains a BST. So in the case where each bean contains a linked list: We can imagine a case where `n/2` first items mapped into one bean. Therefore, from this point every read will take `O(n)` so the overall time complexity is `O(n^2)`. Thank you @amit!